# Is there a way to change mne.io.raw first sample information?

Tags: python, mne-python

I want to modify my raw.first_samp which is an integer that looks like it.

```
Input ->
file = 'yourfilename.fif'
raw = mne.io.read_raw_fif(file)
print(raw.first_samp)

Output ->
100500
```

I would like to put it at 0. But when I try, this is the error I get. I have tried everything but it makes me impossible to set events the right way since they are based on the first samp.

This is the error I get.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_27068/706203670.py in <module>
----> 1 raw.first_time = 0

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Please, I would love to have any help or suggestion concerning this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If anyonye encounter this problem, I am using Python 3.9 and MNE version 0.24.

I made it work by adding this setter into the first_samp property.

```
    @property
    def first_samp(self):
        """The first data sample."""
        return self._first_samps[0]

    @first_samp.setter
    def first_samp(self, first_samp):
        self._first_samps[0] = first_samp
```